# Entering new user data into AD LDS

Tags: active-directory, ad-lds

I need some help configuring **AD LDS** (Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services). I'm not an administrator, have never configured domains and I don't have a clue how to add new users to existing domains. The thing is I need to develop an app on top of Sharepoint 2010 that must be connected to AD. I've chosen AD LDS because I can install it on Windows 7 and it acts as an active directory even though there's no domain controller present in the network.

What I've done so far:

1. I've installed **AD LDS**
2. I've added a new instance with appication directory partition name `DN=Air,DC=Watanabe,DC=pri`
3. I can connect to it using **ADSI Edit** and see all kinds of strange

But now I don't know what to do?

When it opens I can see the window below, but where's next? Can anybody give me some guidelines, how can I add domain users, so I can use them in my app AD required app?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're in for a world of pain trying to get LDS working in place of AD when dealing with SharePoint. It's not really a lightweight version of AD even though its name implies so.

Think of it this way: AD LDS is like SQL server with no databases or tables defined. AD itself is like SQL server with a full schema, databases, set of tables, triggers and stored procedures all defined and ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to follow this technet article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730701%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: That's all fine and dandy, but in the section *Create a OU* I get stuck at step 3. Which node (see upper image) should I click so I can actually create an object type *organisationalUnit*, because I can't find any...

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that AD LDS is ***not*** the same thing as an Active Directory domain; it's only a LDAP database and server, and you're the one which will need to populate it, at a much lower level than the one you're used with when dealing with AD.

If your app requires SharePoint, which in turn requires AD, I don't think AD LDS will be enough; and, even if it will, it'll be a lot more difficult to set up and manage properly than a full-blown AD domain.

If you only need it for development purposes, it would be a lot easier to set up a virtual machine running an actual domain controller; you can do that with as few as 256 MB of memory if you use Windows Server 2003.